# Splitting String N into 4 distinct strings

Tags: c#, string

The string has to be split into 4 pairwise different non-empty parts. For example,

- `"happynewyear"` could become `["happy", "new", "ye" and "ar"`]

No deletion, change of order of characters is permitted.

This question was part of an online competition, which is now over. I have written the following C# code which works for the test cases which I have run but it failed in 3 test cases after submission. I am not sure what cases I might be missing, can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hackerearth___India_Hacks
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var line1 = System.Console.ReadLine().Trim();
            var N = Int32.Parse(line1);
            string[] s = new string[N];
            string result = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                s[i] = System.Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                result = result + "\n" + check(s[i]);
            }
            System.Console.Write(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static string check(string s)
        {
            if (s.Length > 3)
            {
                string[] s1 = new string[4];
                int k = 0;
                string c = "";
                foreach (char ch in s)
                {
                    c = c + ch.ToString();

                    //  Console.WriteLine("C :" +c);
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        s1[k] = c;
                        c = "";
                        k = 1;
                    }
                    else
                        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                        {
                            int f = 0;
                            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
                            {
                                if (s1[j].Equals(c) || c == "")
                                    f=1;
                            }
                            if (f == 1)
                                break;
                            s1[k] = c;
                            c = "";

                            if (k == 3 && s1[k] != null)
                                return "YES";
                            k++;
                        //          Console.WriteLine("K :"+s[k]);
                    }

                }
                return "NO";

            }
            else
            {
                return "NO";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing a link to the competition question and the examples of what works and what doesn't, i.e. input and expected output.

Comment: What are the inputs it failed on, and what are the expected outputs of those inputs?

Comment: I think I found a link to the original site https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/string-division/

Comment: Did my explanation help, Prashant? Anything that I can clarify more?  I've taken those tests, as well... and it also frustrates me that they don't give you all of the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an example which would not work with your algorithm: `"aababa"`.  The 4 strings should be `["aa", "b", "a","ba"]` given your criteria, but your algorithm always assumes that the first character is the first string in the solution.  This assumption is false.  If `"a"` is the first string in the example I give, your algorithm would fail because it would make the first 3 strings `["a", "ab", "aba",...]` that last one would fail with your algorithm because it has no more characters to add to the array.

A recursive solution makes sense to me... here's some code that I think would work.

EDIT: it does work... [here's a dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/07FDtr)

```
public static List<string> FindStrings(string s, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) {
            return new List<string>{ };
        }
        return null; // null means invalid
    }

    for (var i=s.Length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var startOfString = s.Substring(0, i);
        var endOfString = s.Substring(i);
        var list = FindStrings(startOfString, n-1);

        // invalid... gotta continue to next try
        if (list == null) continue;

        // make sure there are no matches so far
        if (list.Contains(endOfString)) continue;

        // bingo!
        if (list.Count == n-1) {
            list.Add(endOfString);
            return list;
        }
    }

    return null; // null means invalid
}
```

Comment: Thanks John,  I missed that part :)

Comment: @PrashantGarje No problem

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this problem is to solve the problem of creating all possible substrings.  Then going through all the possibilities and making sure the results are distinct.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(IsPairwiseUnquie(Console.ReadLine(), 4) ? "YES" : "NO");
  }
}

public static bool IsPairwiseUnquie(string s, int count)
{
  return s.AllSubstrings(4).Any(subs => subs.Count == subs.Distinct().Count());
}

public static IEnumerable<List<string>> AllSubstrings(this string str, int count)
{
  if(str.Length < count)
    throw new ArgumentException("Not enough characters");
  if(count <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("Must be greater than 0", nameof(count));

  // Base case of only one substring, just return the original string.
  if (count == 1)
  {
    yield return new List<string> { str };
    yield break;
  }

  // break the string down by making a substring of all possible lengths from the first n
  // then recursively call to get the possible substrings for the rest of the string.
  for (int i = 1; i <= str.Length - count + 1; i++)
  {
    foreach (var subsubstrings in str.Substring(i).AllSubstrings(count - 1))
    {
      subsubstrings.Insert(0, str.Substring(0, i));
      yield return subsubstrings;
    }
  }
}
```